# Avoid webview redirect

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in my project and its loaded with some initial content. Now when the user clicks on the hyperlink on the `WebView` it **should not reload the `WebView`**, instead it should display the initial content. I tried the below code but it is not working.

```
detailsAndTerms.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){           
    @Override  
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {                         
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add this line of code before return false inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method:
view.loadUrl(url);

Answer (score 3):

```
detailsAndTerms.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){           
     @Override  
     public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)  
     {                          
        if (url != termsurl) {
            // stop loading page if its not the originalurl.
            detailsAndTerms.stopLoading(); 
        }
     } 

});
```

### Update

Try returning false from the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.

```
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
     {                          
        return true;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, its not working for me still the page gets loaded.

Comment: You should returning `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. The documentation says that "return true means the host application handles the url". I feel the webview will not the load the url, since returning true will indicate the url will be handled by the app.